# Data usage consumption in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems

How to control data consumption in windows 10, I tried to solve the problem in many ways it din't work, in the data usage list I saw that a process named system is consuming so much data, is that an exact process or is that the minimum data used by OS to run the computer? Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: What kind of 'data consumption'? Data isn't something that can be eaten; it can be read, written & transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

To monitor process by process, you need more advanced tools like [Netbalancer free](https://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) for instance. You can have a good picture on how the data is being consumed by various processes which normally hide under "OS" tag when using the rather dull in built data monitor by windows.

In a nutshell, many processes which consumed data are controlled by specific services e.g `Background Intelligent Transfer Services` , this service usually transfer files in the background and many applications such as Windows updates, Windows defender (AV definitions update), Windows store etc.

With a tool like Netbalancer for example you'll have more control and disable specific processes from using bandwidth or lower bandwidth requirements etc